# Is there a way to disable user-registrations completely in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

I wonder if there is a way of disable user-registrations **completely**? I have a client that is really in no need of adding users. For me that would be an extreme measure of security. Of course I must be able to add users through code or similar.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried to disable user registration in Administration > Options > General?

Comment: Thanks! It was too obvious ;-)

Comment: Glad you asked this.  Here in December 2017 all I am getting is dozens of signups from *.ru    So I needed to shut it off.  Apparently I can't make it only allow US signups.  Thanks.  Love this database.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can disable your user-registration by routing to Settings > General
and then do the following:

Search a checkbox that says “Anyone can register” Uncheck this, so nobody can register on your blog.
Now when someone accesses the login page, there will no longer be a “Register” link they can use.

http://www.netwebbing.com/wordpress-user-registration-disable/

Also if you still want a registration page, that's kind of secure. Look at the following:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/01/24/how-to-create-an-effective-registration-page-for-wordpress-sign-up/

Comment: This is *security by obscurity* by WordPress. Also known as ***no security***. Hiding the link to the script does not hide/disable the script. Is there an effective way to not allow bots to create 500 subscribers / hour programmatically?

Answer (score 8):

Tried to find a plugin / SO answer to disable user registration completely (as in: prevent bots from registering accounts when `Anyone can register` is ***un*checked**).

Couldn't find any, so I made [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-user-registration/).

Answer (score 7):

Besides disabling checkbox Settings > General > Anyone can register, you may want to add a simple mod_rewite to your .htaccess
@Andrei Gheorghiu is right, Hiding the link to the script does not hide/disable the script.

So, something like that will prevent spam boots to register, return a '403 access denied', and keep your logs lighter

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(wp-login.php\?action=register).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't want to install an extra plugin if there was a simple way around this (and it felt like there was one).

I simply followed the PHP logic that handles registration, and it seemed to point to a single script:

wp-signup.php

I renamed that script, and I am confident there won't be more attacks. I'll update this post in a couple of weeks.

Comment: seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another gaping loophole for account creation that I found on our site was created by WooCommerce.

There is an option under:

```
WooCommerce Settings
Accounts & Privacy
Allow customers to create an account on the "My account" page
```

And the default (at least for us) was to have it on.

Answer (score 1):

Another option -- if you just want to update via DB change:

```
update wp_options set option_value=0 where option_name="users_can_register";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually really easy to find:

[image]

source: https://www.competethemes.com/blog/disable-user-registration-wordpress/

Comment: It is actually really easy to bypass. Please read the comments on your source article.

Answer (score 0):

It prevents of registering users over admin area, REST and xml rpc

I had problem with spam user registration and it helped. Just simply put that in functions.php file

```
function execute_on_register_post_event($sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors){
    wp_die('Forbidden, manualy disabled');
}
add_action( "register_post", "execute_on_register_post_event" , 10, 3);

add_filter( 'pre_user_login' , 'my_username_block' );
function my_username_block( $user_login ) {
    wp_die('Forbidden, manualy disabled');
}
```